# Having CMake include_directories SYSTEM dirs prefix with equals character (=)

Tags: gcc, cmake

Is there a way to have CMake `include_directories` include the system directory prefix with equals(`=`) character? So that I can have gcc prefix the associated dirs with `-isysroot` flag for the cross compilation.

When I try to include the path with equals(`=`) prefix, assumes relative path and prefixes with current source path:

```
include_directories(AFTER SYSTEM "=/usr/include")
```

results:

```
-isystem /root/opencv-2-4-9/opencv/modules/highgui/=/usr/include/
```

what I expect is:

```
-isystem=/usr/include/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the source code of CMake (both 2.8.12.2 and 3.0.0); It seems CMake adds current source directory all paths which are not starting with '/' in non windows systems.

Only exception is generator expressions. If path starts with "$<", then it skips prefixing the path and does not prefix it after evaluation of the generator expression. Therefore

```
include_directories(AFTER SYSTEM "$<1:=>/usr/include")
```

generates

```
-isystem =/usr/include/
```

This seems to be working at least for CMake 3.0.0. Ofcourse you should set CMAKE_SYSROOT for gcc to prefix with proper path.

```
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set it together in one command:

```
set_target_properties(<targetname> PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-isystem=/usr/include/")
```

Comment: Sure there are some alternative solutions. I have already developed some to have a successful build. For example; setting CMAKE_INCLUDE_SYSTEM_FLAG_C and CMAKE_INCLUDE_SYSTEM_FLAG_CXX to "-isystem=" also works.

Comment: My question is can we do this with include_directories? Since CMAKE supports adding -isystem includes and --sysroot flag by CMAKE_SYSROOT, logically there should be support for adding paths with "=" prefix. Otherwise there is no use of CMAKE_SYSROOT, am I wrong?