# What is the difference between "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" and "." in INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES?

Tags: cmake

Should I use

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
    .
)
```

or

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)
```

What is the difference, if any? I've seen mostly "." in existing code, but searching for a dot on the Internet is kind of difficult ...

Answer (score 6):

Both uses generate nearly the same output, since CMake tracks the current directory and replaces the occurrence of "." with "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/.". The only difference is that the "." variant has the extra path component "/." appended.

Whichever you choose is a matter of taste here.

Answer (score 2):

In your case you could think about globally setting [CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR.html) to `ON`.

Regarding your question, the answer depends mainly on your own preferences. I prefer the relative paths variant for the readability of your `CMakeLists.txt` files.

If you look into CMake's source code at [cmTargetIncludeDirectoriesCommand
::Join()](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmTargetIncludeDirectoriesCommand.cxx#L45) and [SystemTools::FileIsFullPath()](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/kwsys/SystemTools.cxx#L4370) you find the following conditions checked by CMake - after expanding the variables - if it will append `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` to the include paths:

- Generally it should *not* contain a generator expression
- On Windows everything that *not* starts with a `\` or `/` and the second character is *not* a `:`
- On Unix everything that *not* starts with a `/` or `~`

In consequence the following CMake code

```
include_directories(.)
get_directory_property(_inc_dirs INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
message("_inc_dirs: ${_inc_dirs}")
```

will show

```
_inc_dirs: [...your CMakeLists.txt path ...]/.
```

This automatic and absolute path prefixing behaviour of CMake makes sense because it's possible - and often recommended - to do out-of-source tree builds in CMake (see also CMake [policy CMP0021](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/policy/CMP0021.html)).

You can think about setting [CMAKE_USE_RELATIVE_PATHS](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_USE_RELATIVE_PATHS.html) to `ON` which will convert the include paths back during generation of the build environment to paths relative to your `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` directory (but it works only with the Makefile generators).

Some additional references:

- [Cmake include_directories()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981534/cmake-include-directories)
- [INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES and relative path](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.programming.tools.cmake.user/25051)
- [Having CMake include_directories SYSTEM dirs prefix with equals character (=)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288504/having-cmake-include-directories-system-dirs-prefix-with-equals-character)
- [Listing include_directories in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902149/listing-include-directories-in-cmake)
- [Tests/IncludeDirectories/TargetIncludeDirectories/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Tests/IncludeDirectories/TargetIncludeDirectories/CMakeLists.txt)