# Cmake can't find source files where they exists

Tags: linux, cmake

I have very simple CMakeLists.txt file.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (test_proj)

set(TEST_INCLUDE_DIR
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")

set(TEST_CPP "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/source_file.cpp"
             "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp")

set(TEST_HEADERS
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/header.h")

#include_directories(${TEST_INCLUDE_DIR})


add_executable(testproj "${TEST_CPP}" "${TEST_HEADERS}")
```

And when I run it like that:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

I get next output:

```
...
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:16 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    /home/me/test_proj/src/source_file.cpp;/home/me/test_proj/src/main.cpp

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx
```

But those files:

```
/home/me/test_proj/src/source_file.cpp
/home/me/test_proj/src/main.cpp
```

Are there. Exactly under that path. Why it can't find them?
If I remove any one of them, so `TEST_CPP` contains just one source file, project generates well. But why it can't if I have more then one source?

I tried `CR LF` and just `LF` as end symbols, result is the same.

cmake version 2.8.12.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put quotes around `${TEST_CPP}`:

```
add_executable(testproj ${TEST_CPP} ${TEST_HEADERS})
```

Otherwise it will add the sources as `;` separated list.

And just a hint: you don't need to prefix everything with `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}` (it's done automatically by CMake).

**Reference**

- [cmake: when to quote variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847655/cmake-when-to-quote-variables)
- [What is the difference between "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" and "." in INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30705284/what-is-the-difference-between-cmake-current-source-dir-and-in-include)

Comment: Yes, that works. Thank you for such deployed answer. In 7 min I will be able to accept it.