# How to setup sysroot for MinGW based toolset?

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, cross-compiling, raspbian

I am using **arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc** compiler toolchain for **RaspberryPi** from http://gnutoolchains.com/raspberry/

It is based on MinGW (as I understood from its documentation). It is installed with sysroot copy from Raspbian with libraries and headers.

**Question**: How to setup a **sysroot** folder (e.g. using env variable) for this toolset?

[image]

For example, when doing **flags.make** contains:

```
C_INCLUDES = -I/opt/vc/include
```

This folder is accessible at **C:\SysGC\raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot**\opt\vc\include.

Toolset binaries are installed in C:\SysGC\raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\bin\ (accessible via %PATH%).

**But compiler and linker doesnt look for libraries and headers in that sysroot folder.**

I can still pass full windows host path for cmake but it will be more elegant and convenient to set it up once and keep original cmake configuration.

I tried do something like

```
set SYSROOT=C:\SysGC\raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot
```

but it does not work. gcc compilers has option --sysroot but that does not seem to be passed correctly via cmake/make toolchain.

Any advice, please?

Comment: Shouldn't the folder be called `sys-root` instead of sysroot?

Comment: This is how the original  installer named it. I can try change it according to your suggestion.

Comment: I tried. The name is correct. After changing it to 'sys-root' the toolset could not found the 'stdio.h' header (it's in \usr\include)

Comment: Can you try compiling a simple application with `-v`, it should tell you what include and library paths are used/searched.

Comment: I played with that option, thanks.
The compiler used is `arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++`. The cmake generates include options in a format `-I/opt/vc/include`. Provided like this makes compiler to look for nonexisting path _/opt/vc/include_. If provided like `-I=/opt/vc/include` the compiler looks correctly in the host sysroot.

Comment: How can I made cmake generating include options like `-I=/opt/include/` instead of `-I/opt/include`?

Comment: I'm not completely sure, are you looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24304959/1983398)?